# Is there a way to update a single pandas dataframe through a dash datatable?

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, plotly-dash

I have a single pandas dataframe which is visualized through two separate dash data tables, that show different aspects of this dataframe, not the whole thing.
One of these data tables is editable, and I want the user to be able to export the changed dataframe after they're done with the editing.

I read about storing the dataframe in a hidden div and then converting it into json, but it seems that this qay is used when the whole dataframe is accessible through the data table, which is not the case for me.

Is there any way to deploy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Dash Core Components (dcc) [Store](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) object to hold the dataframe in your layout. You can then create a callback that will update some or all of this dataframe when a change is applied to the data table.

As an example:

Given your layout file has a Store component, e.g.:

```
app_layout = html.Div([dcc.Store(id='my-dataframe')])
```

Then the following callback will read/write the dataframe.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('my-dataframe', 'data'),
    Input('my_trigger', 'my trigger'),  # Set this to whatever should trigger the callback
    State('my-dataframe', 'data')
)
def update_dateframe(my_trigger, my_dataframe):
    if my_dataframe is not None:
        df = pd.read_json(input, orient='records')
    else:
        pass # Do whatever you need to do to initialise the dataframe 

    # Do whatever you need to do to update the dataframe.

    return df.to_json(orient='records')
```